# OperationalError: no such table: books on python anywhere

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, pythonanywhere

I have a file structure on python anywhere as :

flaskhost(folder) which contains :

1. app.py
2. books.db

app.py contains -:

```
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify
import sqlite3

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return '''<h1>Distant Reading Archive</h1>
<p>A prototype API for distant reading of science fiction novels.</p>'''


@app.route('/api/v1/resources/books/all', methods=['GET'])
def api_all():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('books.db')
    conn.row_factory = dict_factory
    cur = conn.cursor()
    all_books = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM books;').fetchall()

    return jsonify(all_books)



@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return "<h1>404</h1><p>The resource could not be found.</p>", 404


@app.route('/api/v1/resources/books', methods=['GET'])
def api_filter():
    query_parameters = request.args

    id = query_parameters.get('id')
    published = query_parameters.get('published')
    author = query_parameters.get('author')

    query = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE"
    to_filter = []

    if id:
        query += ' id=? AND'
        to_filter.append(id)
    if published:
        query += ' published=? AND'
        to_filter.append(published)
    if author:
        query += ' author=? AND'
        to_filter.append(author)
    if not (id or published or author):
        return page_not_found(404)

    query = query[:-4] + ';'

    conn = sqlite3.connect('books.db')
    conn.row_factory = dict_factory
    cur = conn.cursor()

    results = cur.execute(query, to_filter).fetchall()

    return jsonify(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial

> https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-apis-with-python-and-flask

my site is hosted at :

> http://vivanks.pythonanywhere.com

But when I call api by

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/resources/books?author=Connie+Willis

It show me error :

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: books

Any help how to fix this and host app on pythonanywhere.com ?

P.S On my local machine it's working perfectly fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Pythonanywnere, When pointing to content other than templates or static files (stored in their own proper directories, accessible by `flask`), you have to provide the full path:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/your_username/flaskhost/books.db')
```

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: @MansiShukla Glad to help!